# IE doesn't display png images

Tags: internet-explorer, png

Internet Explorer (doesn't matter if 8, 9, 10, 11) won't display any png images of my website. (www.oenomarketing.de) It only shows a cross and the alt text. The pngs work in Chrome and Firefox. IE does display the png images of other websites. 
It is a WordPress Website with a Theme based on Bootstrap 2. Another Site I run with another Theme (Divi) does display the pngs without a porlem. So it must be related to my WP-Theme.

Update
If I open the local Version (DesktopServer) of the Website it displays the pngs in IE. Just the live Version is making trouble.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, still struggling on finding the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Because the content-type of the file in the http header is wrong.

Comment: So, how to fix it?