# Backgroung Image is not Loading on IE11 If I use PNG file

Tags: html, png, internet-explorer-11

I just created a simle HTML page having a background image in png format. This is properly working with Forefox and Chrome. In IE11, it is not working. 
This is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Login Page </title>
</head>
<body style="background-image:url(Image1.png)">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried enclosing them in single quotes? `background-image:url('Image1.png')`

Comment: please check your IE settings to show pictures.

Comment: Using Single quotes did not helped.

Comment: @AshishPatel Where can I exactly look for that property??

Comment: go to this link and follow steps for IE.
http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000813.htm

Comment: @AshishPatel jpeg format is working. But, PNG file is not working.

Comment: Is the problem with a particular PNG file, or does any PNG file fail to be displayed?

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson The problem is with every PNG file.

Comment: Just a guess: try replacing url( 'Image1.png') with url('./Image1.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this bug when the image is invalid and IE, edge doesn't allow the image to render.

**FIX**: check the image mime type and change the extension according to the mime type.

(http://checkfiletype.com/)

1. image/jpeg
2. image/png

screenshot of error (sample_banner_607.png), mime type of this image was ***image/jpeg***

[image: IE png bug screenshot]

So when I change the extension back to JPG, it works (sample_banner_607.jpg).

[image: image loaded]

References

1. https://www.w3.org/Graphics/
2. [IE doesn't display png images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076928/ie-doesnt-display-png-images)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason .ie11 needs a width property attached to it. You can do this with css.

`.ie11 body{
width: auto;
}`

Comment: Apart from that, even if I use background attribute, it is not working.